# Error on AndroidManifest when recompiling

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have an error in `AndroidManifest.xml` on line 2 when recompiling, any mistakes?

```
<manifest xmlns:"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="143"
     android:versionName="8.10.0.2824" 
     package="kik.null"
     platformBuildVersionCode="21"
     platformBuildVersionName="5.0-1504858">
```

Comment: What exactly is the error message?

Answer (score 1):

Try `android:VersionCode="21"` instead of `platformBuildVersionCode="21"` and `android:VersionName="5.0-1504858"` instead of `platformBuildVersionName="5.0-1504858"`.

Comment: Changed answer after I testes my previous best guess.

Comment: Also: `kik.null` isn't a good package name. `null` can't be used as a part of a Java package name because it is a literal. Therefore, the generated [R class](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html) won't be in a valid package.